# Como utilizar dois pacotes que utilizam Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator

Tags: laravel

Em meu projeto possuo dois pacotes [`LaravelLegends/pt-br-validator`](https://github.com/LaravelLegends/pt-br-validator) e [`nuwave/lighthouse`](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse) ambos utilizam o contract `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator` para fazer a validação dos campos, gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar ambos no mesmo projeto?

Atualmente o **lighthouse** está sobreescrevendo o **pt-br-validator** e retornando este erro: `"Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateTelefone does not exist."`

Comment: Poderia ser a sintaxe? algumas APIs usam pt-br outras pt_br outras pt-BR e outras pt_BR

Comment: Opa @VitorCeolin pior que não, vi aqui que o `laravellegends/pt-br-validator` e o `nuwave/lighthouse` ambos utilizam o contract **Validator** e como o **lighthouse** esta sendo executado depois acaba sobrescrevendo  o **pt-br-validator**

Comment: Cria uma issue nos repositórios de mais os pacotes avisando do problema, eles devem corrigir ou sugerir uma solução, mesmo que temporária

Comment: @Costamilam vou fazer isso mesmo!! por hora consegui achar uma solução paliativa para isso, mas tive que me desfazer o projeto PtBrValidator e criar as minhas próprias regras de validação.

Comment: @ThiagoCosta na versão atual do lighthouse não identifiquei nenhum uso do `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator` que sobrescreva as regras do outro pacote. Quais versões de Laravel e dos pacotes você está utilizando?